# IDE deduce Python type

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I am writing a method in Python, which looks something like this:

```py
def rgb_to_grayscale(image):
    print(image.shape)
    pass
```

The one expected type here is `numpy.ndarray`, which is basically an image in OpenCV. How is it possible for the IDE to deduce the type of this object beforehand, so I get autocompletion inside the method?

I am using PyCharm. If anyone knows any other IDE which is capable to do so, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python 3.5, you can use [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing):

```py
def rgb_to_grayscale(image: numpy.ndarray):
```

---

Also, Pycharm is capable of recognizing types by [defining them in the docstring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html). I prefer this option as it is more clear (in my opinion) and forces you to actually write a docstring - which is very important for production code (and in general). You could do something like:

```py
def rgb_to_grayscale(image):
    """
    :param numpy.ndarray image: the image to be printed
    """
    print(image.shape)
```

---

More ways Pycharm can detect types, in [this help link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add type hint to the function signature

```
def rgb_to_grayscale(image: numpy.ndarray):
    print(image.shape)
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use :**

```py
def rgb_to_grayscale(image: numpy.ndarray):
    print(image.shape)
```

This is applicable to all data types. If some other value is passed as an argument then it will raise a `AttributeError`